# SAP and Private Domains

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was wondering if i could confirm some assumptions I have around SAPs and Private domains.

Can 1 SAP be provisioned to a BU as well as multiple Private Domains associated with the same IP?

With links, am I correcting in assuming that urls such as (click.domain.com, pages.domain.com) can only be configured to to one domain? Even if multiple private domains are there for the BU?

Answer (score 4):

**First question** - yes, you can have a SAP and multiple Private Domains configured to one MID and all associated with one IP.

Private Domain does not include a Dedicated IP on it's own, it is only used as an authentication tool.

In addition, Private Domains are not as comprehensive as SAP's and there is no limitation on how many you can configure per MID.

**Second question** - correct again, only the SAP comes with branding, and that is indeed limited to just 1 per MID.

- [Private Domain overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240073&language=en_US&type=1)
- [Marketing Cloud SAP details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hm - I always see a dedicated IP in conjunction with a private domain - by not included does that mean it's a paid add-on?

Comment: Yes, by default Private Domain SKU's do not have IP in the package unless specified otherwise in the Order Form. However when purchasing a SAP package (which can be done per Business Unit) it's possible to have a new dedicated IP for each of them.